# What's the proper design of a data reading/storing application?

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I need to read 200,000 or so records from a website and store them in DB. The application is a desktop app implemented on top of Netbeans Rich Client Platform. By using Apache HttpComponent library, I can send request to the website and retrieve the response that contains the record information; then using regex, I can fairly easily extract the dozen of fields that I need from the HTML.

I am thinking to have 2 worker threads besides the GUI thread. One worker thread handles the HTTP request/response part and also extracts the record from the HTML using regex; while the other worker thread stores the records into DB. So, there will be a data structure to hold the records so that it can be shared between the two worker threads. I am also considering to have a buffer of size 100 (for example) for the HTTP worker thread to store the records, and when the buffer is full, transfer 100 records at one time to the shared records holder.

Please comment on my design and also my questions are:

1. what is the proper data structure to hold the records?
2. how to synchronized it between the two worker threads?
3. how would the multi-threads be implemented in the modular system of Netbeans Platform?

Comment: what does the NetBeans IDE have to do with this?

Comment: @Brian: NetBeans IDE != NetBeans Platform http://netbeans.org/features/platform/

Comment: @Esko thank you for the clarification. I'd only ever heard the term used in reference to the IDE and had never heard of the platform.

Comment: Is this a one-time application? If so, you could probably write it simple (and inefficently) in a single thread and run it faster than design one that's going to be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the proper data structure to hold the records?

Depends on the data. Probably a simple class with a bunch of fields (preferably [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) to make using multiple threads safer).

> how to synchronized it between the two worker threads?

One of the [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations might be good for that. [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) can be used as a fixed-size buffer for passing work between the threads.

> how would the multi-threads be implemented in the modular system of Netbeans Platform?

No idea whether NetBeans Platform has anything to say about that. Launching your own threads should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. BlockingQueue is the right one. I should probably ask if Swing has anything to say here, if I want the progress to be shown on the UI. How about using a SwingWorker?

Comment: With Swing you need to take care that UI updates are processed in the event dispatch thread (see class javax.swing.SwingUtilities). Swing also has a progress bar component which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this kind of HTML parsing would slow down your app quite badly. Also, the code would be quite fragile since HTML changes quite often for aesthetic enhancements. You should resort to 'HTML scraping' as the last resort. Most customers agree to opening up a web-service/data-service for this once you explain the disadvantages.

If you really have no other alternatives, then I think your approach is good. But instead of waiting for the buffer to be full, you could have a set of threads writing into the buffer and a set of threads reading from the buffer simultaneously. I would suggest using more number of HTTP scraper threads and less number of DB-write threads since the HTTP request-response cycle and HTML parsing would be order of times slower than a database write.

Comment: I really have no other choices then HTML scraping. Fortunately, I am pretty sure that the HTML format won't change.

Comment: Regarding the number of threads, your suggestion makes sense. However, if I have multiple HTTP scraper threads, it's hard, if not impossible, to divide work between them and let them know when to stop: the records have IDs starting from 1, and keep increasing, problem is that some numbers in between are skipped. Currently, I compare the total # of existing records to the # of records being processed. But if I have multiple scraper threads, how would I know how many are processed in total?